# Android studio 3 capture cant automatically store hprof

Tags: android, hprof

When I do a heap dump, I cant see the hprof file in the Captures

[image: android developer description]

Comment: Please, first read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah, that panel seems to be useless now :-/